# Diferença no casting em Java

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo, cast

Qual a diferença entre os 2 códigos abaixo?

1º

```
int x = 10;
float i = (float) x;
```

2º

```
int x = 10;
float i = Float.parseFloat(x);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É bem simples, o primeiro funciona e o segundo não, não faz sentido fazer um *parsing*  em um número inteiro, apenas em *strings*. Então [a documentação mostra que só pode passar uma *string*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)).

Aliás o nome do método é um "primor" :P

O primeiro indica que um número que era inteiro deva ser interpretado como um tipo de ponto flutuante binário. Haverá uma conversão porque os formatados de cada tipo é diferente. Na verdade funciona sem isso, há uma conversão implícita de `int` para `float` conforme [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda