# Por que é necessário fazer "(char)" antes de usar em uma string?

Tags: java, string, char, cast

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class String5 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    String s, maius, minus;
    char c;
    int i, n;

    System.out.printf("Informe uma string:\n");
    s = ler.nextLine();

    n = s.length(); // tamanho da string
    maius = ""; // string convertida em maiúsculas
    minus = ""; // string convertida em minúsculas
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
      c = s.charAt(i);
// verifica se o i-ésimo caractere é alfabético minúsculo
      if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z'))
// converte o i-ésimo caractere no correspondente maiúsculo
         maius = maius + (char)(c - 32);
      else maius = maius + c;
// verifica se o i-ésimo caractere é alfabético maiúsculo
      if ((s.charAt(i) >= 'A') && (s.charAt(i) <= 'Z'))
// converte o i-ésimo caractere no correspondente minúsculo
         minus = minus + (char)(c + 32);
      else minus = minus + c;
    }

    System.out.printf("\nResultado:\n");
    System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n", maius, minus);
  }

}
```

Nas linhas onde tem as variáveis `maius = maius + (char)(c - 32);` e `minus = minus + (char)(c + 32);` não entendi o porque tem que chamar este `(char)`. Quando eu tiro do código, e o meu input é com letras maiúsculas, tudo ocorre bem, mas quando o input são com letras minúsculas, o primeiro resultado retorna os números correspondente a cada letra na tabela ASCII.

O que não entendi é o que exatamente esse `(char)` está fazendo ali.

Comment: Apesar de não ser em Java, talvez esse link ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/446070/112052 - pois a ideia é basicamente a mesma

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você quer acrescentar na *string*? Um número ou um caractere?

Se você não usar nada o que será colocado é um número, afinal só números você consegue fazer contas.

Java tem uma semântica de converter qualquer dado  para `String` se parecer que precisa. Isso pode gerar confusão, mas foi a escolha feita pela linguagem para facilitar algumas operações, mas parece ir contra a filosofia da linguagem. Então quando você tenta somar um número em um texto a conversão é feita e o número, da [tabela ASCII](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156951/101), é concatenado no texto. Se a linguagem não tivesse tomado essa decisão não precisaria disso.

Como na verdade você deseja o caractere correspondente àquele código numérico da tabela ASCII você precisa dizer para o compilador converter o número para o caractere, e o [operador de *cast*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/272116/101) pode ser a solução, é exatamente o que faz o `(char)`.

[Diferença entre casting e promotion](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102345/101)

Falei um pouco sobre [representação ser diferente do número](https://pt.quora.com/Como-%C3%A9-que-os-computadores-sabem-o-que-fazer-com-1-e-0-Sempre-que-tento-descobrir-as-pessoas-limitam-se-a-explicar-o-c%C3%B3digo-bin%C3%A1rio-nunca-dizendo-como-um-computador-sabe-por-exemplo-pegar-no-0110-e/answer/Antonio-Maniero).

De qualquer forma tem um jeito mais fácil, semântica e segura de fazer a mesma coisa se fazer isso que é quase uma gambiarra em Java, já que tem forma melhor pronta.

Dei uma melhorada no código mas não arrumei o problema que performance que ele tem, até porque em exercício em volume baixo não muda nada, mas entenda que esse código não é bom para usar em produção, como a performance não é objetivo tornei ele mais simples, ainda que mais lento (também tem o problema de não fechar o `Scanner`, mas tudo bem para exercício):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Informe uma string:\n");
        String s = (new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine();
        String maius = "";
        String minus = "";
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') maius += Character.toUpperCase(c);
            else maius += c;
            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') minus += Character.toLowerCase(c);
            else minus += c;
        }
        System.out.printf("\nResultado:\n%s\n%s\n", maius, minus);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qH1RSs). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/qsbnmbgadd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/CharUpperLower.java).

- [Quando usar StringBuilder e StringBuffer no lugar de concatenação com operador "+" em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/340481/101)
- [Por que ainda usar a String em vez de StringBuilder no Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/448326/101)
- [String e sua eficiência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16063/101)

Também evite abreviar coisas sem necessidade só para digitar menos, o código fica mais difícil de ler e precisa de comentários.

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui entender sobre o cast e agora faz muito sentido.
Só para pontuar, esse código eu peguei pelo DevMedia que estava lendo uma artigo deles onde possuia esse trecho de código (neste artigo não estava falando sobre cast). Mas obrigado pelas dicas e documentações.